# How to change Kong realm name

Tags: kong, kong-plugin

Any Kong authentication plugin (key-auth, basic-auth) produces a response header "www-authenticate" with a realm="kong".
Is there a way to change the value of realm to something that doesn't indicate which API gateway I'm using?

I read the docs of the authentication plugins but there is no config value for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I build my own docker image, I decided to patch the value directly in the source code. For anyone interested, here is the line in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN cd / && find . -name "meta.lua" 2>/dev/null | xargs sed -i.lua 's/_NAME = "kong"/_NAME = "<my-own-realm-name>"/g'
```

The command searches for the `meta.lua` file and replaces the value of the `_NAME` variable. Maybe it could be more elegant, but it fits my needs.

Answer (score 0):

> I read the docs of the authentication plugins but there is no config value for that.

The `WWW-Authenticate` header is sent to the client to comply with [section-4.1 of RFC 7235](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7235#section-4.1) which specifies that  `A server generating a 401 (Unauthorized) response MUST send a WWW-Authenticate header field containing at least one challenge.`
It is implemented here on the source code
[here](https://github.com/Kong/kong/blob/master/kong/plugins/key-auth/handler.lua#L146).

However, Since the header is a response from Kong in case of 401 response (request not passed through to the upstream server), The header can be altered without any problem.

You can use the [response transformer](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/response-transformer/) plugin with configuration of `config.replace.headers=WWW-Authenticate:<value>` to change the value of the header.

Otherwise, the configuration of `config.remove.headers=WWW-Authenticate` can be used to remove the header completely.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I know that I can use the response transformer plugin, I already use it for some routes. However, I was looking for a more elegant solution - some configuration value either globally or at least directly in the auth plugin config. And I don't like the idea to have every request go through that plugin just to remove the header. I decided to patch the value directly in meta.lua.

Comment: Yea... If you want to remove the returned header without plugins, fiddling with Kong source code may be the best solution. Have you considered creating your own plugin and loading it into Kong? might solve your problem directly.

Comment: I have an own plugin and I tried to change the value of _KONG._NAME from there, but I didn't find out how I could guarantee that the code is executed before the auth plugin creates its local realm line - which also seems to happen directly when the plugin code is loaded. Sometimes it worked and sometimes not.

Comment: Have you tried to make your plugin run before auth plugins? maybe set it at 9000-ish? If your plugin run before auth plugin and change the value before 401 response happen and setting Header, the value should be changed.